# scopes of variables in Java

Tags: java, scoping

In Java, you don't have declare a method physically before you use it. The same thing doesn't apply for variables.
Why is this the case? Is it just for "legacy" reason (ie., the Java's creators didn't feel like doing it), or is it just not possible?

Eg.,

```
public class Test
{
    // It is OK for meth1 to invoke meth2
    public void meth1() { meth2(); }
    public void meth2() { }

     // But why is it NOT ok for field1 to reference field2
     private int field1 = field2;
     private int field2 = 3;
}
```

If I wanted my Java compiler to support this kind of forward-reference, what is the general idea as to how to do it? 
I understand there'd be issue about circular depencies, which we'd need to be careful about. But other than that, I really don't see why it should not be possible.

[Edit]Ok, here's my initial thought as to how to do this.
While analysing the code, the compiler would build a graph of dependencies for the variables in the given scope. And if it sees a loop (ie., `int a = b; int b = a`), then it would throw an error. If there is no loops, then there must be some optimal way to re-arrange the statements (behind the scence) such that a field will only reference fields declared before it, and so it shouuld try to figure out the order. I haven't worked out the exact algorithm, but I think it is possible. Unless someone can *scientifically* prove me wrong.

**Recap the question:**
Say I'm trying to build my own dialect of Java, which supports this sort of scoping. My main question is, **could you give me some ideas as to how to do this**

Thanks

Comment: Imagine you are the runtime executing the line `private int field1 = field2;` What value you should set for `field1`?

Comment: To answer yourself, put yourself in the compiler's shoes..

Comment: Assuming field2 were accessible when field1 was assigned, would you expect it to be assigned 0, 3, or something else? I don't think 3 is a reasonable option here since the constructor has to do the assignments in order; and 0 would just make the code confusing.

Comment: What is the computational complexity of any algorithm that detects graph cycles? Is it worth adding that to every compilation? To answer that question, answer; what is being gained by allowing this language feature?

Comment: The complexity shouldn't really matter is it? This is done at compile-time.

Comment: Your question has moved from one centered on understanding a design decision of the language to a very broad, open-ended question on how to implement scoping in a compiler.

Comment: @OneTwoThree Complexity matters at compile time; length of compilation time directly impacts developer productivity.

Comment: Well, practically speaking, no one is going to have more 100 variables in a scope, so although I do agree with you that compiling would be slower, I don't think it would be that much slower.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [JLS, Section 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1), initialization of class variables proceeds from top to bottom, in "textual order":

> The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order, and may not refer to class variables declared in the class whose declarations appear textually after the use, even though these class variables are in scope (§8.3.2.3). This restriction is designed to detect, at compile time, most circular or otherwise malformed initializations.

So, if you make your own compiler to recognize forward class variable declarations, then it is violating the Java Language Specification.

Comment: That's what I was waiting for.

Comment: +1 for citing the spec, which happens to explain the purpose for it.

Comment: (Just update the question. Please take a look at it, if you have a moment)

Comment: @OneTwoThree Sure, you could do this, but my point is that it would no longer be officially Java.

Comment: Well, ok, it doesn't matter. Say I'm trying to build my own dialect of Java, which supports this sort of scoping. My main question is, could you give me some ideas as to how to do this

Comment: @OneTwoThree: If you try doing that, you'll probably run into the same issues Java tried to avoid by banning this approach, e.g. cyclical, nonsensical initializations.  Why would you do that?

Comment: Well, short answer, why not? I don't agree with the idea that you shouldn't do something simply because people think it's a bad idea, which is then still very subjective, or that a problem which was avoided isn't a problem that is worth solving. Personally, I just think it'd be cool to be able to do this. (And even if the compiler that supports would make devs stupid, then it'd still be worth it. :D )

Answer (score 4):

I will give you a simple piece of code:

```
public class Test
{
    private int foo = bar;
    private int bar = foo;
}
```

What would you expect this to do?

I presume that designers of Java has done it so because assignment of values to instance variables must be executed in some order. In the case of Java, they are executed downwards (from up to bottom).

## **EDIT**

What about this?

```
public class Test {
    private int foo = quu++;
    private int bar = quu++;
    private int quu = 1;
}
```

What values would `foo` and `bar` have? Which `quu++` statement would be executed first?

My point is, Java designers must have thought that it is counter intuitive to do it as you did describe in your question, i.e. unordered execution with compile time code analysis.

## **FINAL EDIT**

Let's complicate things:

```
class Test {
    private James james = new James(anInt);
    private Jesse jesse = new Jesse(anInt);
    private IntWrapper anInt = new IntWrapper();
}

class James {

    public James(IntWrapper anInt) {
        if(--anInt.value != 0) {
            new Jesse(anInt);
        }
        else {
            anInt.isJames = true;
        }

    }
}

class Jesse {
    public Jesse(IntWrapper anInt) {
        if(--anInt.value != 0) {
            new James(anInt);
        }
        else {
            anInt.isJames = false;
        }
    }
}

class IntWrapper {
    public int value = 99;
    public boolean isJames;
}
```

I am not sure what it proves regarding your question because I am not sure about your point.

There is no circular dependency here but value of an instance variable of IntWrapper, `isJames`, depends on the execution order and it might be difficult to detect this kind of stuff with a lexical/semantic analyzer.

Comment: I know, I would think the compiler should be able to issue an error about circular dependency here.

Comment: I mean, it is highly feasible to detect this sort of loops in code-analysis phase.

Comment: What if the second variable is set to something not determinable at compile-time but is at execution time? What should the private field be set to? While it is 'feasible' it is not 'ironclad' to detect unresolvable situations. Compilers should be ironclad - and anyway, what is achieved?

Comment: Sorry if my wordings gave the wrong idea of what I was tyring to ask. Just updated the question. Please take a look at it again, if you have a moment

Comment: @OneTwoThree I have provided another problematic case. I will look further into your question as it is an interesting one :)

Comment: Ok, I would think the algorithm, which I haven't been able to fully devise yet, should be able to take the original order into account. In other words, since there are two possible ways to re-arrange `int foo ...` and `int bar ...`, it would go back and see what statement actually came first, and because `foo` came first, it should be placed first

Comment: @OneTwoThree I added one more example.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the order of initialization. Fields are initialized top to bottom. In your example, when `field1` tries to reference `field2` in the initializer, the latter is yet to be initialized itself.

The rule about forward references is aimed at catching the most obvious cases of this problem. It does not catch all; for example, you can still do:

```
 private int field1 = getField2();
 private int field2 = 3;
 private int getField2() { return field2; }
```

and get `field1` intialized to zero where you might be expecting `3`.

Comment: Regarding your example, the same is true for `final` fields if you leak the `this` reference.

Answer (score 0):

How will `field1` know value of `field2` before it has been defined and assigned a value?

Comment: I think his point is, how does `method1` knows how to call `method2` before it has been defined and assigned a ... block I guess?